# C/C++ Windows traffic blocker

Tags: c++, c, windows, network-programming, ndis

I want to develop a bandwidth allocator to a network which will be behind my machine.

Now, I've read about NDIS but I am not sure whether the network traffic that is neither originating from my machine nor is destined for my machine will enter my TCP/IP stack, so that I can block/unblock packets via NDIS on a windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

NDIS (kernel) drivers live in the Windows network stack, and so can only intercept packets which are handled by this stack.

You cannot filter packets which are not send to your computer.

(When the computer acts as a router, the packets are send to the computer and the computer forwards the packets to the actual recepient, if that was the question)

Answer (score 0):

In normal operation mode the irrelevant traffic will be dropped by the NIC driver/firmware, like pointed above. However, this is a SW issue so this behavior can be changed by adding an appropriate logic into the device driver and/or firmware. This is how sniffers operate, for example.